# AntiResourceLocking on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

We're running Tomcat8 on Windows and redeploying applications sometimes fails due to Windows locking jars of properties.

I found this documentation saying that you have to add the `AntiResourceLocking`-attribute to a `Context`-element: [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)

All our servers are built using scripts so doing this in the `server.xml` should not be a problem (if it works?):

```xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context antiResourceLocking="true"></Context>
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

When the server restarts Tomcat prints the following errors and we have no real clue as to what is wrong:

```
Failed to initialize component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[null]]

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[null]]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getObjectKeyPropertiesNameOnly(StandardContext.java:6233)
```

Has anyone done this before? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

What you are missing is the difference between `conf/server.xml` and `conf/context.xml`.

When you add a `<Context .../>` element to `conf/server.xml` you are defining an individual context (web application). This is equivalent to defining a `<Context .../>` element in `CATALINA_BASE/conf/<engine-name>/<host-name>/<context-name>.xml` or in a `/META-INF/context.xml` file packaged as part of the web application.

The `<Context .../>` element in `conf/context.xml` defines defaults for all contexts (web applications).

The single Context element you have adding in `conf/server.xml` is failing because you haven't specified a path.

If you really want to enable anti-resource locking for all web applications then you need to add antiResourceLocking="true" as an attribute to the `<Context .../>` element in  `CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`.

As an aside, this option is only a work-around for resource leaks in your web application. You might want to consider taking the time to fix those resource leaks.

Comment: I tried inserting a simple line `<antiResourceLocking>true</antiResourceLocking>` in context.xml, but Tomcat aswered: __org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Context/antiResourceLocking'__.

Comment: `antiResourceLocking` is an attribute, not an element. You want `<Context antiResourceLocking="true" />`

Answer (score 2):

Visit http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html for recommended way.

You can define context.xml in META-INF/context.xml in you WAR or
you can define conf/Catalina/localhost `WAR_NAME.xml`

- To configure **antiResourceLocking** in xml add following tag in context.xml

  `<Context antiResourceLocking="true"></Context>`

Answer (score 0):

For me I had a very similar problem when have 2 applications on same tomcat but on different ports, defined as 2x **Service** tags in **Server.xml** file. One of configured service couldn't start. And logs were similar to described.

Problem was in invalid docBase in `<Context docBase="/appliccation2" ...>` path, for tomcat installed on Windows and working local the relative path were enough, but for tomcat configuration on linux server defined path in my situation should be direct location `<Context docBase="/opt/.../webapps/application2" ...>`

Answer (score -2):

Please check all servlet classes accurately mapped in web.xml and also confirm their path is physically exist on the server. This is what cause to throw `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed` exception.