# FAIL - Application already exists at path /Teste

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

Good night, I'm having a problem that I don't know if is the Linux, the tomcat, maven or netbeans. I'm trying to debug a project but it return that error:

```
Implantação em andamento... (Implementation ocorring...)
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext5869996979793086537.xml&path=/Teste
FAIL - Application already exists at path /Teste
```

Someone had that problem or know how to resolve that? I passed all day trying to resolve but nothing
I'm using Linux Mint Cinnamon, IDE NetBeans 8.2, TomCat 8.5.23.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered an error like "Application already exists at path /Teste",
I did the following:

```
1. "Debug / Finish Debugger Session" (red square toolbar button),

2. Navigate to the "Undeploy" command as follows:

Window (menu) / Services
  Services (pane)
    Servers
      Tomcat 8.5
        Web Applications
          /Teste

3. Right click "/Teste" and click "Undeploy" in the popup context menu.

4. "Debug / Debug Project" now worked.
```

Answer (score 0):

"This can be fixed by  adding  to tomcat context. The  antiResourceLocking is by default set to false. More details can be read at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html."

SOURCE: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/deploying-artifacts-to-tomcat-will-sometimes-fail-on-due-to-file-locking-397083103.html

-> antiResourceLocking: "If true, Tomcat will prevent any file locking. This will significantly impact startup time of applications, but allows full webapp hot deploy and undeploy on platforms or configurations where file locking can occur. If not specified, the default value is false.

antiJARLocking is a subset of antiResourceLocking and therefore, to prevent duplicate work and possible issues, only one of these attributes should be set to true at any one time.

Please note that setting this to true has some side effects, including the disabling of JSP reloading in a running server: see Bugzilla 37668.

Please note that setting this flag to true in applications that are outside the appBase for the Host (the webapps directory by default) will cause the application to be deleted on Tomcat shutdown. You probably don't want to do this, so think twice before setting antiResourceLocking=true on a webapp that's outside the appBase for its Host."

SOURCE: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Introduction

Some more elaborate answers here: [AntiResourceLocking on Tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153700/antiresourcelocking-on-tomcat-8)

LE: as a quick fix I manually deleted the file "yourapppathname.xml" at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\Catalina\localhost...

Answer (score -1):

1. Method 1:
   Create a new project then copy all the files: source and web.
   Remember: It is important to copy web.xml
2. Method 2:
   project => meta-inf => context.xml then change the path.
   There are 2 ways I use, wish you good learning